# Trying to rotate a layout in android, canvas does not appear to rotate

Tags: android, android-layout, touch, rotation, ondraw

I've taken the tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/) (which dynamically rotates an image on touch/fling) and tried to refactor it with a whole layout instead of just one image, so I've changed the rotateDialer() method from the TutorialActivity like so:

```
private void rotateDialer(float degrees) {
    //matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight / 2);
    //dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    dialer.setNextRotation(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight  / 2);
    dialer.invalidate();
    info.setText("Current Quadrant Touched = "+currentQuadrantTouched
            +"\nAngle = "+degrees);
}
```

where dialer is a custom layout I've created with an overridden onDraw() method that rotates the canvas however many degrees set in the setNextRotation() method, but the canvas does not appear to rotate! Here is my custom layout:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class DialView extends FrameLayout {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "DialView";
RelativeLayout dialView;
float degrees;
float px;
float py;

public DialView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DialView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public DialView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    init();
}


private void init()
{
    //initialise rotation
    this.degrees = 0;
    this.px = 0;
    this.py = 0;
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    dialView = (RelativeLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.dial_view, this,false);
    addView(dialView);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DialView: init() "+ degrees+"degrees around ("+getWidth() / 2+","+getHeight() / 2+")");

}



public void setNextRotation(float degrees, float px, float py)
{
    this.degrees = degrees;
    this.px = px;
    this.py = py;
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Next Rotation = "+ degrees+"degrees around ("+px+","+py+")");
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    // canvas.rotate(45,<appropriate x pivot value>,<appropriate y pivot value>);
     canvas.rotate(degrees, px, py);
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDraw: Rotation = "+ degrees+"degrees around ("+px+","+py+")");
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.restore();

}


}
```

this is the dial_view.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topLeftImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topRightImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottomLeftImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bottomRightImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why does the canvas not visibly rotate? I'm invalidating the dialler in onTouch() after the calculation of the degrees, and the calculation is working correctly (I'm getting changing values in the log) but the view just doesn't seem to be rotating, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this is an old post but just spend a couple of hours on understanding this: Above will work if you move canvas.save(); before canvas.rotate(degrees, px, py);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it turns out the onDraw() method was never being called, I just simply had to add

```
setWillNotDraw(false)
```

to my init() function and hey presto the onDraw() method is being called, and my view is rotating!!!!

Comment: as i said above, i just had to write "setWillNotDraw(false)" into my init() function. if you put that line onto your constructor methods for your class that will work too. The original code snippets in the original question itself will work by doing this, feel free to copy it and insert the line into either the DialView() constructors or the init() function

Comment: I inserted code as, you said, but the view remains same,.. not rotating at all.. I can see log of angles too

Comment: is the log being called from the onDraw method or from elsewhere?

Comment: I debugged through, onDraw is calling every time after touching buttons but its they are moving , yes the log is also from onDraw too..

Comment: That code seems fine - the problem most likely lies wherever you are calling the setNextRotation() method (i.e. wherever these 'buttons' you mentioned above are)

Comment: This is my Next rotation called method, all looks very fine but layout is not moving an inch http://pastebin.com/dNMHdCxH